# Why first spaces and tabs are black in vim?

Tags: vim

I need to add some plugins to vim but first spaces and tabs are black yet. How I can fix it?

[image]

And my list of plugins is here:

```
Plugin 'edkolev/promptline.vim'
Plugin 'tomasr/molokai'
Plugin 'scrooloose/nerdtree'
Plugin 'tpope/vim-markdown'
Plugin 'suan/vim-instant-markdown'
Plugin 'bronson/vim-trailing-whitespace'
Plugin 'kien/rainbow_parentheses.vim'
Plugin 'bling/vim-airline'
Plugin 'ervandew/supertab'
Plugin 'Raimondi/delimitMate'
Plugin 'scrooloose/syntastic'
Plugin 'scrooloose/nerdcommenter'
Plugin 'nathanaelkane/vim-indent-guides'
Plugin 'godlygeek/tabular'
Plugin 'MatlabFilesEdition'
```

Comment: Do you have any `match` statements in your `.vimrc`?

Comment: Could you please show us your .vimrc?

Comment: If I had to guess this has to do with the indent-guides plugin (third from the bottom).  Try disabling it.

Comment: becasue `Plugin 'nathanaelkane/vim-indent-guides'` ?

Comment: @AlexKroll You are right! Very Thanks!